reading pdf files in vba
I tried many ways to read pdf files in vba code which i use on word but nothing worked.txt and docx files work but not pdf.
here is my code:
Sub AutoOpen()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strSourceFolder As String
    Dim strDestinationFolder As String
    Dim myFile As String, text As String
    Dim isTXT As Integer
    

    myFile = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "/desktop/file.pdf"
    
    
    

    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    
    
    
    ' Check if the file is a .txt file
    If Right(myFile, 4) = ".txt" Then
       
        Open myFile For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline
            text = text & textline
        Loop
        Close #1
    ElseIf Right(myFile, 4) = ".pdf" Then
        ' Here the code for pdf

    ElseIf Right(myFile, 5) = ".docx" Then
        ' Initialize Word application
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = False ' Don't show Word window
        
        ' Open the .docx file
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(myFile)
        
        ' Extract text from the document
        For Each objRange In objDoc.Paragraphs
            text = text & objRange.Range.text
        Next objRange
        
        ' Close the document and Word application
        objDoc.Close
        objWord.Quit
        
        ' Clean up objects
        Set objRange = Nothing
        Set objDoc = Nothing
        Set objWord = Nothing
    End If
    
   

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "https://website.com/"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send text

End Sub

I tried many ways and i got errors like Object creation through activeX component not possible.
I would appreciate every answer

What software do you want to open the PDF in? You don't show us the code you have tried for opening PDFs. "Here the code for pdf" is not very useful...
